# Golang Architecture questions for new project

Tags: go, architecture

I'm using this https://medium.com/@eminetto/clean-architecture-using-golang-b63587aa5e3f architecture for my next project.

But I have a few questions:

- In which layer should caching go?
- In which layer should authentication/authorization go?

And is this a good architecture to use with Go?

Answer (score 0):

- What do you want to cache, the database queries or files or requests?
- Authentication/Authorization can be in the middleware layer and also
  before the view/model layer.

You can pick and choose your architecture based on your need and objectives. There is no hard and fast rule for choosing the architecture. The right architecture comes out from trying POC on different architecture for the same objective.

Comment: Well I thought that there are some architectures which really work.

Comment: Well it depends on your goal and objectives of the project. What’s your goal(performance, concurrency ... etc)  and which domain?

Comment: The goal is to make a platform for residents to manage their contracts and payments. Later on we want to add social/community features. So it needs to be very flexible

Comment: Is it something like a real estate classified app for posting, renting and buying/selling property?

Comment: Mostly for renting

Comment: Ok. I am not seeing any challenge in picking the architecture the need is quite straightforward I would suggest choosing any framework to save time and money. Django, Drupal, Wordpress, Openhippo ... etc